# How when click button order in custom siri intents make custom action

Tags: ios, swift, shortcut, siri

[when click button order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0QCR.png)

i need when click in button make custom action (default here dismiss view only)

A specific action, such as push to a viewController within the applicatio

I did a lot of searching but couldn't find anything that helped me. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.